# Access variable within exception from another class

Tags: java, oop, exception

I need to validate if an exception is true but from another class

i have 2 classes `class_a` and `class_b`

Here are the classes:

```
public class Class_a {

static boolean pru = false;

public static boolean Getpru() {
    return pru;
}

public static void Setpru(boolean setAValue) {
    pru = setAValue;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Class_a a = new Class_a();

    Class_b b = new Class_b();

    int entr = 0;

    try {

        System.out.println("Enter a number");

        entr = scan.nextInt();

    } catch (Exception e) {



        a.Setpru(true);

    }

    b.val();

} }
```

i'm changing the value of `pru` to true when it falls in the exception

Here's the second class

```
public class Class_b {

Class_a a = new Class_a();

public void val() {

    if (a.Getpru()) {

        System.out.println("There is a misktake in the value");
    } else {

        System.out.println("The value is correct");
    }

}
```

}

The problem i have is that in `class_b` the `pru` value does not match the `class_a` boolean value

Comment: scan is not declared in your code !

Comment: please give us some feedback about your tests

Comment: Sure @Lu15 
It marks and error in `b.val(this)`

Comment: -The method val() in the type Class_b is not applicable for the arguments 
- Cannot use this in a static context

Comment: I've updated my answer @blazedosan002

Comment: @Lu15 with the update it marks the error
-The method val() in the type Class_b is not applicable for the arguments (Class_a)

Comment: @blazedosan002 did you modified "Class_b" adding "Class_a" as a first parameter? public void val(Class_a a)

Comment: @Lu15 Yes i did like so `public void val(Class_a a) `

Answer (score 0):

Your are using wrong instances, the first time you check the "pru" value you are using "instance 1" of "Class_a" but when you validate inside "Class_b" your are using a brand new instance... try the following:

**Class_a**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Class_a a = new Class_a();
    Class_b b = new Class_b();
    int entr = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        entr = scan.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        a.Setpru(true);
    }
    b.val(a);
}
```

**Class_b**

```
public class Class_b {
    public void val(Class_a a) {
        if (a.Getpru()) {
            System.out.println("There is a misktake in the value");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The value is correct");
        }
    }
}
```

That way "Class_b" will use the same "Class_a" instance.